# How to import xml2js in an angular2 app using angular-cli with webpack

Tags: xml, angular, angular-cli, xml2js

For an application using angular2 (from angular-cli with webpack), i need to consume some data in xml  from a soap web service.The angular-cli that i use provide natively the library xml2js for parsing xml to json  but when i try to use this library in my component using the following syntax:

```
import {Parser} from 'xml2js';
```

i got the message:

```
Cannot find module 'xml2js'.)
```

However, this library is really installed on the node_modules file.

I searched everywhere but i only found some solutions with system.js config.

Does anyone know how to use this library in an angular2 using webpack?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to install the type definitions for xml2js

NPM:

```
npm install @types/xml2js --save-dev
```

YARN:

```
yarn add @types/xml2js -D
```

Comment: @AndreiDiaconescu could you expand on why you believe this doesn't work anymore? This is only installing the types for that package.

Comment: You have to run `npm install --save stream timers` to make it work with Angular 6

Answer (score 0):

I would add this to JJB's answer.
Got the same problem. I solved it by installing theses 3 dependencies:
sax/ xmlbuilder/timers

***- npm install @types/xml2js --save***

- npm install --save @types/sax
- npm install --save @types/xmlbuilder
- npm install --save @types/timers

---

Or

- ***npm install xml2js --save***
- npm install --save sax
- npm install --save xmlbuilder
- npm install --save timers

---

see:

- https://npmmirror.com/package/xml2js/v/0.4.0
- [xml2js in Angular 6: Can't resolve 'stream' and 'timers'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52106505/xml2js-in-angular-6-cant-resolve-stream-and-timers)

Regards