# xml2js in Angular 6: Can't resolve 'stream' and 'timers'

Tags: javascript, xml, angular, typescript

I would like to parse xml data, retrieved from the server. Unfortunately `HttpClient` does not support xml, only json, therefore I installed the package `xml2js`:

```
npm install xml2js --save
npm install @types/xml2js --save-dev
```

Then I try to use it like this:

```
import {Parser} from 'xml2js';

Parser.parseString(xml_str, function (err, result) {
    console.dir(result);
});
```

I get these two errors if I run it:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/xml2js/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\projects\app\node_modules\xml2js\node_modules\sax\lib'

ERROR in ./node_modules/xml2js/lib/parser.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'timers' in 'C:\projects\app\node_modules\xml2js\lib'
```

I haven't found any solutions to this problem, maybe it is an Angular6 issue only. Is there any way, to parse xml in Angular6?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You’ll have to install those dependencies. It’s unfortunately not well documented.

```
npm install --save stream timers
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it only allows compiling. The npm timers package does not provide function setImmediate, so at the runtime an error (TypeError: setImmediate is not a function) is still thrown. Something about that is here: https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js/issues/301 but it still does not suggest a solution.

Comment: btw. stream and timers last commit is over 5..7 years ago.

Comment: Thanks a lot. this solved my problem like charm! :)

Answer (score 29):

For Angular to recognise xml2js, the following steps are required:

1. Add the timers-browserify node module using "npm install timers-browserify"
2. Add the stream-browserify node module using "npm install stream-browserify"
3. Add the following path mapping in your tsconfig.json:

```
    "compilerOptions": {
      "paths": {
        "timers": [
          "node_modules/timers-browserify"
        ],
        "stream": [
          "node_modules/stream-browserify"
        ],
      }
    }
```

Comment: This resolved the issue I was having `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream'`, thanks!

Comment: Why did you only say install and not install --save? Everyone seems to do this can't figure out why, if the person doesn't do --save they will have to explicitly re-add it every time?

Comment: This solution worked for me Thanks

Comment: Perfect, this worked!. (Angular 14). I'm gratefully.

Comment: @DanChase Starting from npm version 5 and later, npm introduced the automatic saving of dependencies without the need for the `--save` flag. You don't need to type `--save` explicitly if you're using newer version of npm.